# How to iterate two arrays in CoffeeScript

Tags: for-loop, coffeescript

I'm trying to rewrite example from classic book "JavaScript: The Good Parts" in CoffeeScript via list comprehensions:

```
var parse_url = /^(?:([A-Za-z]+):)?(\/{0,3})([0-9.\-A-Za-z]+)
 (?::(\d+))?(?:\/([^?#]*))?(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?$/;

var url = “http://www.ora.com:80/goodparts?q#fragment”;
var result = parse_url.exec(url);
var names = ['url', 'scheme', 'slash', 'host', 'port', 'path', 'query', 'hash'];
var blanks = '       ';
var i;
for (i = 0; i < names.length; i += 1) {
     document.writeln(names[i] + ':' +
         blanks.substring(names[i].length), result[i]);
}
```

I can't get how to write loop and stuck with this code:

```
console.log "#{name}: " for name in names
```

Comment: Have you read http://coffeescript.org/#loops ?

Comment: Sure I read, but it doesn't help me.

Comment: You haven't listed what you have tried, what problems you ran into, what errors your seeing, nothing. What else can we do but point you towards the documentation?

Answer (score 3):

I imagine you are trying to do something [Like this](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aparse_url%20=%20/%5E%28?%3a%28%5BA-Za-z%5D%2b%29%3a%29?%28%5C/%7B0,3%7D%29%28%5B0-9.%5C-A-Za-z%5D%2b%29%28?%3a%3a%28%5Cd%2b%29%29?%28?%3a%5C/%28%5B%5E?#%5D%2a%29%29?%28?%3a%5C?%28%5B%5E#%5D%2a%29%29?%28?%3a#%28.%2a%29%29?%24/%0A%0Aurl%20=%20%27http://www.ora.com:80/goodparts?q#fragment%27%0A%0Aresult%20=%20parse_url.exec%28url%29%0A%0Anames%20=%20%5B%27url%27,%20%27scheme%27,%20%27slash%27,%20%27host%27,%20%27port%27,%20%27path%27,%20%27query%27,%20%27hash%27%5D%0A%0Aalert%20%22#%7Bnames%5Bi%5D%7D%3a%20#%7Bresult%5Bi%5D%7D%22%20for%20i%20in%20%5B0..names.length-1%5D%0A)

```
parse_url = /^(?:([A-Za-z]+):)?(\/{0,3})([0-9.\-A-Za-z]+)(?::(\d+))?(?:\/([^?#]*))?(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?$/

url = 'http://www.ora.com:80/goodparts?q#fragment'

result = parse_url.exec(url)

names = ['url', 'scheme', 'slash', 'host', 'port', 'path', 'query', 'hash']

alert "#{names[i]}: #{result[i]}" for i in [0..names.length-1]
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need, thanks! But are you sure that your solution written in CoffeeScript way?

Comment: @surganov I'm not sure what you mean by that?

Answer (score 1):

In case someone comes here actually needing to iterate two arrays at the same time, this works:

```
for [course_event, remote_event] in zip(course.events, remote.events)
  course_event.lessons = remote_event.lessons if event.lessons_need_updating
```

`zip()` is from [here](https://coffeescript-cookbook.github.io/chapters/arrays/zip-function):

```
zip = () ->
  lengthArray = (arr.length for arr in arguments)
  length = Math.min(lengthArray...)
  for i in [0...length]
    arr[i] for arr in arguments
```